# Get this error auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment using express nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase in my project but getting this error `auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment` when login with google credentials.

.hbs file code

```
<span class="google-bg session-icon">
  <a href="#!" id="google" onclick=" return loginWithGoogle(this)">
      <i class="ti-google"></i>
   </a>
</span>
```

script code

```
function loginWithGoogle(event){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/session/google/login",
       type: "POST"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
    error= JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(error);
    M.toast({html: error})
 });
}
```

Express code

```
router.post('/session/google/login',function (req, res, next){
   //console.log('get resqust');
   firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(googleAuthProvider).then(function(result){
       console.log(result);
   }, function(error){
      console.log(error.code);
      res.json({
         data: error.code
      })
   });   
})
```

When I click on Google icon then call `loginWithGoogle` function and get the router path `/session/google/login` after that execute express code and generate error. I`m wondering to resolve this issue and what could be wrong ?

Thankyou!!!

**Updated(16-10-18)**

Call dashboard route after successfully login with Gmail account.

```
router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
      if(firebase.auth().currentUser != null){
         res.render('dashboard', { 
            title: 'App'
         });
      }else {
      req.session.error = 'Access denied!';
      console.log(req.session.error);
      res.redirect('/login');
   }
});
```

After successfully login with gmail account I have call dashboard route and using condition before render the dashboard page but `currentUser` returns null. I have check in Firebase console that shows recently new user login  with gmail and if i have login with simple userid and password then `currentUser` returns the data. where i`m wrong ??

Updated 17-10-18

```
function loginWithGoogle(event) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
       .then(function (user) {
           // localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
           window.location.href = '/dashboard'; 
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            var email = error.email;
            var credential = error.credential
        })
    }
```

After successfully login I have redirect to `'/dashboard'` and express call defined route for dashboard. which I have mention yesterday. now please tell me where I call dashboard route??

Answer (score 5):

Before you start check that you've added firebase to your front end if you didn't do it yet here are instructions how to do it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Login with Google is done on front end and its pretty simple, you don't need to change your html code, only javascript like below and no need to call cloud functions

```
function loginWithGoogle(event){
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```

This is only one of use cases when you sign in by redirect, there are sign in with pop up and more complex handling of sign in that you can try after you will make this one to work: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

For authenticated calls to your cloud functions you need to get token first and then make a call. But you can do it only after you have already signed in.

```
function authenticatedCallToFunctions(event){
  firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {"firebase-token": idToken}
      })
      .done(function (data) {
        error= JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(error);
        M.toast({html: error})
      });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
}
```

And you can process your authenticated request in cloud functions like

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

router.post('someurl',function (req, res, next){
  var token = req.headers['firebase-token'];

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(function(result){
      console.log(result);
  }, function(error){
     console.log(error.code);
     res.json({
        data: error.code
     })
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. I have update my question and stuck  again with page rendering condition. May you help.

Comment: As you might know JavaScript is asynchronous, so my suggestion that you call your dashboard route not after, but before successful sign in

Comment: I have update my code. After successfully login I have redirect to `'/dashboard'` and express call defined route for dashboard. which I have mention yesterday. now please tell me where I call dashboard route??

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Authentication SDK for JavaScript only works in the browser, not in a node.js environment.  If you need to work with Firebase Auth on your backend, you'll need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which you can use to [manage user sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions).

Comment: Do you elaborate more about implementation with nodejs experssjs ??

Comment: You should refer to the Firebase Admin SDK link provided by @Doug.

Comment: I dont see why you would think he certainly isn't using the SDK already. This error doesn't only occur when somebody isn't using the SDK.